# UrlFetchApp Google Scripts VS Node Fetch

Tags: node.js, post, google-apps-script, http-status-code-403, urlfetch

I'm having some problems to do a simple POST request with UrlFetchApp on Google Scripts.

This code works fine on NodeJS with node-fetch lib.

```
const fetch = require('node-fetch');
const URL = "https://login.XXXXXXXXXXXXX.com.br/api/login"

fetch(URL, {
  "body": "{'my_json_data': 'login data'}",
  "method": "POST",
}).then(res => res.text())
  .then(body => console.log(JSON.parse(body)));
```

The same request on a Google Scripts project using UrlFetchApp give me a 403 Forbidden HTTP error.

```
var url = 'https://login.XXXXXXXXX.com.br/api/login';
  var data = {
    'email':'EMAIL',
    'password':'PASS'
  }

  var options = {
    method: 'POST',
    payload: JSON.stringify(data)
  }

  var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url, options);
  Logger.log(response)
```

What am I missing here?

Edit: Already tried with payload.

Answer (score 0):

I believe your goal as follows.

- You want to convert the following Node.js script to Google Apps Script.

  ```
    const fetch = require('node-fetch');
    const URL = "https://login.XXXXXXXXXXXXX.com.br/api/login"

    fetch(URL, {
      "body": "{'my_json_data': 'login data'}",
      "method": "POST",
    }).then(res => res.text())
      .then(body => console.log(JSON.parse(body)));
  ```

#### Modification points:

- In your Node.js script, the data of `"{'my_json_data': 'login data'}"` is sent to `data` as `text/plain`. So in this case, when UrlFetchApp is used, the content type is required to be set. Because when the content type is not set, the data is sent as `form-data`.

When above points are reflected to your script, it becomes as follows.

#### Modified script:

From:

```
var options = {
  method: 'POST',
  payload: JSON.stringify(data)
}
```

To:

```
var options = {
  method: 'POST',
  payload: JSON.stringify(data),
  contentType: "text/plain"
}
```

- If `contentType: "text/plain"` occurs an error, please modify it to `contentType: "text/plain;charset=UTF-8"`.
- Although I'm not sure about the specification of your API, I thought that `contentType: "application/json"` might be able to be also used. But this is my guess.

#### Reference:

- [Class UrlFetchApp](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/url-fetch/url-fetch-app)